# Unable to deploy an Android app to emulator

Tags: xamarin, deployment, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I created a default Android project using Xamarin Studio.

When I'm run the project, the emulator (Kitkat XXHDPI Phone (API 19))
opened properly, but project did not deploy and start debugging.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [read this guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions properly on this forum. First and foremost, what is the issue you experience?

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Could you post the ADB log from the emulator

Comment: No, I dont see any error messages.

Comment: I dont see apk file also